# FullCalendar retrieve all IDs when drag element with same GroupId

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I use jQuery FullCalendar with PHP and MySql. I have an unsolved problem with the function EventDrop (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDrop)

```
eventDrop: function (info) {
            alert (info.event.id);
            alert (info.event.title);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'agenda_deplacement_evenement.php',
                // Others parameters

            });
        },
```

When I move a single element, info.event.id and info.event.title give me the id and the title of the element, no problem.

But when I move multiple element with the same GroupId (Events that share a groupId will be dragged and resized together automatically), I would like to retrieve all the Id and title moved in an array for example.

After hours of searching, I am really blocked

Thanks for the help. appreciate it.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to run [getEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents) to get all events, and then find all the ones with the same group ID from that (by doing your own filtering). I don't see any other way.

Comment: @ADyson You give me the way I did not see . Thank You so much

Comment: I am using FullCalendar with Quasar/Vue, so I saved event by group id in a store. It's easy to get list of event id.